# MySQL Syntax Error Error

Tags: php

When calling my function a MySQL Syntax Error appears, any ideas?

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

```
function getComments1() {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments") or die(mysql_error());
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $post['Author'];

    }
}

function addComment($cName, $cContent) {
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES(null,'$cName','$cContent'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

---

```
<?php
include('includes/functions.php');
mysql_set_charset ( "utf8" );

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['CommentName'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['CommentContent'])) {
            addComment($_POST['CommentName'],$_POST['CommentContent']);
            header("Location: derger.php");
        } else { "text missing";

        }

    } else {
        echo "name missing";
        include('herger.php'); 
    }

} else {
    header("Location: werger.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: probably due to unescaped charactors, use PDO or mysqli (Parametrize Query) for preventing from SQL injection.

Comment: Adding to @Akam's comment, the 'mysql' extension is deprecated in PHP 5.5 and you are advised to use mysqli or PDO instead. More on that here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 3):

```
("INSERT INTO comments VALUES(null,'$cName','$cContent'")
```

You didn't close the values. should be:

```
("INSERT INTO comments VALUES(null,'$cName','$cContent')")
```

Also, as everyone here will remind you, mysql_ functions are deprecated. You should be using PDO or MySQLi. A simple google search on either will give you plenty of resources to transition into.

Answer (score 2):

The error is you are missing the closing parenthesis in your insert query.  Update the query as follows:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES(null,'$cName','$cContent')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Note the closing parenthesis after `'$cContent'`.

Other notable issues are, you are still using `mysql_` extensions which is deprecated and you should start using either [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  Please also note that your current implementation is vulnerable to SQL injection attack, you should at the very least implement [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).  Please have a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection